# bash interactive session from subprocess

Tags: python, bash

I working on cli, in some cases i want to open shell and give control to user, then wait for shell session terminate and continue execution.

I have this code, it works, but it only reading input and writing output. I want to support all features my shell provide, like printing working directory before commands or tab completion. How i can do it ?

```py
import subprocess
import os, sys
import time


def read(stream):
    try:
        return stream.read()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

def main():
    shell = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    os.set_blocking(sys.stdin.fileno(), False)
    os.set_blocking(shell.stdout.fileno(), False)

    while True:
        print_data = read(shell.stdout)
        input_data = read(sys.stdin)

        if print_data:
            sys.stdout.write(print_data.decode())
        
        if input_data:
            shell.stdin.write(input_data.encode())
            shell.stdin.flush()

        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: A call to `subprocess.run(["/bin/bash"])` would start an interactive bash process.

Comment: @liginity, yes, it's working, but i can't figure out how i can execute in this session some commands before give control to user.

Comment: Do you mean to execute some commands in the started bash process, and then give control to the user?

Comment: @liginity, yes, i need to setup some environment variables, launch migrations, launch service, and so on, and then give user terminal.

Comment: sorry, I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: sounds like you need [tag:pexpect].

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells, yes, pexpect allow that, thanks for pointing on right direction.

Comment: You can put your commands in init-file, then do bash —rcfile init-file